# How to resolve angular lang json file(angular-localization module) from jasmine test case

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have angular service method which uses  angular-localization locale service .
I want to write jasmine test cases for  method , which are failing as jasmine is not able to
resolve it. May be it is not waiting till it resolve completely

```
//service method
$scope.getExcelName = function() {
  var name = locale.getString('export.fileName')
  return name;
}

//lang file 
'fileName': 'Status Report'

//Jasmine test case
describe('Service:MyService', function() {
  var myService
  beforeEach(module('app'))

  beforeEach(inject(function($injector) {
    myService = $injector.get('MyService');
  }))

  it('check export name', function() {
    //myService.getExcel giving '' instead of  Status Report
    expect(myService.getExcelName()).toBe('Status Report')
  })
})
```

How  to resolve above issue ?

Comment: Shouldn't you inject scope and call digest in order to make it happen?

Comment: I am not sure if you can pass first class functions to expect: you pass myService.getExcelName and you don't invoke it, try: expect(myService.getExcelName()).toBe('Status Report'). You want to pass first class functions in case you spy them, so: expect(trackedFunction).toHaveBeenCalled();

Comment: Do you mean to write `expect(myService.getExcelName())` instead of `expect(myService.getExcelName)`?

Comment: Also, please include the full service code. It looks like what you are showing us is part of a directive or a controller.

Comment: @AndrewEisenberg I mean to write  myService.getExcelName()

Comment: Please edit your question to reflect the actual code. And please include the relevant code for the service.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are experiencing a race condition (excerpt from the documentation):

> Race conditions
>
> Always use locale.ready() passing in the filename(s)
>   in which the token(s) exists in that context, and enclose any other
>   relevant calls to locale.getString() within this promise's callback
>   function block. Failure to do so may cause unexpected (empty) results
>   due to the asynchronous nature of your entire JavaScript application.
>
> You may use locale.getPath() to find the filename for any given token.

So the solution should be to inject the `locale` service and wrap the `expect` line inside a `locale.ready()` call, e.g.:

```
it('check export name', function(done) {
  locale.ready('export')
    .then(function() {
      expect(myService.getExcelName()).toBe('Status Report');
      done();
    })
    .catch(done.fail);
});
```

Probably you should also do the same in the service itself to be safe.

Comment: it block execute sequentially it does not wait for any asynchronous behavior . locale.ready creates  promise .I tried  this  it did not work.

Comment: You're right, I forgot to add the async handling for the test. Depending on the test framework you're using, you can either pass the 'done' property to the test callback (I updated the code in the answer with this solution) or return the promise with `return locale.ready('export').then(function() { ...`.

Comment: I have tried this and got  error "Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL."

Comment: Then the call to `locale.ready('export')` is either throwing an error or hanging somehow. I have updated the code above to add error handling so you see the error if there is one and you can probably understand what's going on.